# AudioBufferSourceNode starts playing only after being connected

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

In my object, I got an `AudioBufferSourceNode` object (`this.bSrc`), connected to a gain node (`this.audioDestination`) that plays a (valid) `AudioBuffer` already stored in the object (`this.audioBuffer`).

If `this.audioDestination` is connected to the audio context final destination `this.mainContext.destination` and I call the `start(0)` method on my `AudioBufferSourceNode` object (`this.bSrc`), it will play fine.

If, instead, `this.audioDestination` is *not yet* connected to the Audio Context final destination, the buffer won't play (and it's ok), but its playback will be delayed until the connection is made (thus invalidating any assumption on when the AudioBufferSourceNode finishes playing).

I'm currently implementing a plugin architecture, in which every plugin has its audioDestination gain node and doesn't (and must not) know whether it is indirectly connected to the final Audio Context destination. What seems logical to me is that the AudioBufferSourceNode should 'play' immediately and finish, even if it's not connected to the final Audio Context destination. But it seems it doesn't work like this. Am I right or am I getting it wrong? Is there some way to change this behaviour?

Code:

```
/* Create the audio Context. */
this.mainContext = new webkitAudioContext;

/* Create an audio gain node */
this.audioDestination = this.mainContext.createGainNode();

/* [...] An AudioBuffer gets decoded and stored into this.audioBuffer*/

/* Create an AudioBufferSourceNode and try to play it immediately */
this.bSrc = this.audioContext.createBufferSource();
this.bSrc.connect (this.audioDestination);
this.bSrc.buffer = this.audioBuffer;
this.bSrc.start(0);

/* Create a callback for when the AudioBufferSourceNode finishes playing */
if (!this.bSrc.loop) {
       var pbTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            this.playFinishedCallback();
        }.bind(this), this.audioBuffer.duration * 1000 / this.bSrc.playbackRate.value);
    }

 /* Connect this.audioDestination to the final AudioContext destination */
 /* If this statement is executed after the previous ones, playback will start NOW */
 this.audioDestination.connect(this.mainContext.destination);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way the Web Audio API is currently implemented in Chrome, and the design used therein.  There's been talk of changing it; in fact, I was a proponent of the "audio cable model" you describe.  :)  It's not the only sane model, though.  There isn't any way to change this behavior in current implementation.

However, there is an easy workaround - simply keep a zeroed-out gain node connected to context.destination, and connect all your ABSNs to that as well as their (eventual) connection to the context.destination.

Comment: Yeah, thinking about it I've seen similar models before. I suppose that the context.destination is the one "pulling" the data, so nodes aren't asked anything if they aren't connected to the destination in the connection graph. The advantage is that, for example, any intensive  ScriptNode won't suck CPU until it's connected, the disadvantage is that the model doesn't fit well in a typical audio environment.
The workaround seems logical (at least, from a programmatical point of view) and easy to implement, though. Thank you!

Comment: Btw, you are Chris Wilson! I appreciate your contributions on html5rocks and your Web Audio Playground was as a font of inspiration for my current project (an audio plugin host, built on web audio api). Nice to meet you.

Answer (score 0):

This makes sense.  Think of context.destination as stdout.  Without connecting to context.destination, the audio has nowhere to go.  If you move the last line (connecting to context.destination) up to just after you create the gain node, I don't think you'll have a delay.

Comment: is that a guess of yours or do you have some evidence that Web Audio API is designed that way? To me, it makes little sense. Think about connections as cables, audio nodes as instruments / effects and the context destination as a pair of speakers. If you detach the cable that goes from your instrument (e.g. a music keyboard) to the speakers, the instrument actually 'plays' when you press a key (though you can't hear anything), it doesn't wait for the cables to be attached to play back all the keys you pressed at once. Instruments don't behave like Unix pipes.

Comment: I didn't realize that it was actually delaying the start of playback.  That is a little weird, still seems like you can work around it by connecting to your destination before trying to play.